# convert c++ libraries to objective-c

Tags: c++, objective-c, malloc

Now I am porting c++ game to objective-c.

The source code uses some dlls such as "malloc.h" and this is the standard dll of C++ so it

cannot be included in objective-c.

What is the best way to overcome this problem.

I hope your help.

Thanks.

Comment: malloc.h is not a DLL - and is C so is part of objective C (and really should not be used in C++)

Comment: C++ can be used with objective-c in a `.mm` file

Answer (score 4):

To convert code from one language to another, you need to have at basic working knowledge of both languages and platforms involved. It sounds as if both your C/C++ and Objective-C knowledge is too rudimentary for you to undertake this task. I'd recommend you take a short course and work on small  projects in both languages to gain some experience so that you'll be qualified to perform this translation.